# Video Element not being detected in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows

Tags: windows, safari, html5-video, modernizr

I'm running Safari 5.1.7 on windows 7.

I'm got a HTML 5 Video element playing on my website, and I use modernizr to test if video is supported before running the video script.

According to caniuse.com, [video is supported for Safari 5](http://caniuse.com/video). However, in the console, `Modernizr.video` is returning false. Why is it returning false, when video should be supported for this browser?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: Safari needs also the quicktime plugin.

Answer (score 0):

how did you embed your video? which video format are you using? please provide more information!

`Safari` only supports `MP4` format, if you only provide `ogg` or `WebM`, this could be one reason for the error. Another could be that your missing your mime-types. Either in the videotag (look code example),

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">  //safari support
 <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">  //no safari support
</video>
```

or on the server side. you can set them in your .htaccess file like

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
```

Comment: Modernizr is returning false, even if I didn't have any videos embedded on the page, modernizr would still feature detect. But to answer your question, I'm embedding all 3.